# Always show reload menu in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

As some of you may be aware, Chrome has a reload menu that will show up if you have developer tools open and you click and hold the reload button.

I don't always have developer tools open, but I frequently need to do a hard reload. I'd love if there were an option in chrome's settings so I can just turn the menu on all the time, but I can't find one.

Could there be a way to modify chrome so it always shows the reload menu, regardless of whether I have developer tools open or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can get the menu at all times but you can always do a hard reload using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>r</kbd>

Comment: that's a good point, I'll just start doing that instead. That'll be a lot easier than trying to hack the browser somehow :)

Comment: Unfortunately after doing this for a couple of days I don't think it works as expected. It seems like if I don't have developer tools open it doesn't actually do a hard reload. Several times now I've uploaded a changed stylesheet then tried CTRL + SHIFT + R and saw no change. Then I opened dev tools and tried again and the changes were visible.